# PyObjC methods not accessable

Tags: python, pyobjc

I recently discovered `pyobjc` and wanted to install it.

Like in the documentation said I installed it with `pip install pyobjc`. The installation was successful and everything worked. But when I tried to import for example `NSObject` from the `Foundation` module it did not work. It just said that the module `Foundation` does not have an attribute called NSObject.

I am using Mac Version 11.4, Pycharm and `Python 3.9`

Why is that? Or did I miss something?

Comment: Do you have XCode installed?

Comment: @MattDMo not yet. Do you need it to write the code? I thought you just need it to compile the code.

Comment: With an IDE like Pycharm, it compiles parts of your code in the background in order to provide features like code intelligence/autocompletion, variable introspection, and so on. I would install XCode and the command-line tools, so you have the SDKs available that PyObjC is linking to.